# NameError: undefined local variable or method `demo_app' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

I am very new to learning rails and trying to get past this error as I work through the Hartl tutorial.

I ran scaffolding and then

`rake db:migrate`

and cant get past the below:

```
rake db:migrate
rake aborted!

NameError: undefined local variable or method ``demo_app' for main:Object
/Users/terencefox/rails_projects/demo_app/Rakefile:7:in ``<top (required)>'
/Users/terencefox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in ``eval'
/Users/terencefox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I barely know what all this means so thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Add you Rakefile in your post

Comment: can you paste the rakefile content here?